# How to pass value using useEffect and props in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to pass `props.Name` value to other script but is giving me `undefined`. What is wrong with this code?

```
  export default function Tile(props) {

  const videoEl = useRef(null);
  const audioEl = useRef(null);
  const nameEl = useRef(null);

  /**
   * When video track changes, update video srcObject
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    videoEl.current &&
      (videoEl.current.srcObject = new MediaStream([props.videoTrack]));
  }, [props.videoTrack]);


  useEffect(() => {
    nameEl.current &&
      (nameEl.current = "Mohd Jamshaid");
  }, [props.Name]);

  /**
   * When audio track changes, update audio srcObject
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    audioEl.current &&
      (audioEl.current.srcObject = new MediaStream([props.audioTrack]));
  }, [props.audioTrack]);

  function getLoadingComponent() {
    return props.isLoading && <p className="loading">Loading...</p>;
  }

  function getNameComponent() {
    //var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999));
    return props.Name && <p className="name" ref={nameEl}>{props.Name}</p>;
  }

  function getVideoComponent() {
    return (
      props.videoTrack && <video autoPlay muted playsInline ref={videoEl} />
    );
  }


  function getAudioComponent() {
    return (
      !props.isLocalPerson &&
      props.audioTrack && <audio autoPlay playsInline ref={audioEl} />
    );
  }

  function getClassNames() {
    let classNames = "tile";
    classNames += props.isLarge ? " large" : " small";
    props.isLocalPerson && (classNames += " local");
    return classNames;
  }

  return (
    <div className={getClassNames()}>
      <div className="background" />
      {getLoadingComponent()}
      {getVideoComponent()}
      {getAudioComponent()}
      {getNameComponent()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

to this script

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import "./Call.css";
import Tile from "../Tile/Tile";
import CallObjectContext from "../../CallObjectContext";
import CallMessage from "../CallMessage/CallMessage";
import {
  initialCallState,
  CLICK_ALLOW_TIMEOUT,
  PARTICIPANTS_CHANGE,
  CAM_OR_MIC_ERROR,
  FATAL_ERROR,
  callReducer,
  isLocal,
  isScreenShare,
  containsScreenShare,
  getMessage
} from "./callState";
import { logDailyEvent } from "../../logUtils";

export default function Call() {
  const callObject = useContext(CallObjectContext);
  const [callState, dispatch] = useReducer(callReducer, initialCallState);

  /**
   * Start listening for participant changes, when the callObject is set.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!callObject) return;

    const events = [
      "participant-joined",
      "participant-updated",
      "participant-left"
    ];

    function handleNewParticipantsState(event) {
      event && logDailyEvent(event);
      dispatch({
        type: PARTICIPANTS_CHANGE,
        participants: callObject.participants()
      });
    }

    // Use initial state
    handleNewParticipantsState();

    // Listen for changes in state
    for (const event of events) {
      callObject.on(event, handleNewParticipantsState);
    }

    // Stop listening for changes in state
    return function cleanup() {
      for (const event of events) {
        callObject.off(event, handleNewParticipantsState);
      }
    };
  }, [callObject]);

  /**
   * Start listening for call errors, when the callObject is set.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!callObject) return;

    function handleCameraErrorEvent(event) {
      logDailyEvent(event);
      dispatch({
        type: CAM_OR_MIC_ERROR,
        message:
          (event && event.errorMsg && event.errorMsg.errorMsg) || "Unknown"
      });
    }

    // We're making an assumption here: there is no camera error when callObject
    // is first assigned.

    callObject.on("camera-error", handleCameraErrorEvent);

    return function cleanup() {
      callObject.off("camera-error", handleCameraErrorEvent);
    };
  }, [callObject]);

  /**
   * Start listening for fatal errors, when the callObject is set.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!callObject) return;

    function handleErrorEvent(e) {
      logDailyEvent(e);
      dispatch({
        type: FATAL_ERROR,
        message: (e && e.errorMsg) || "Unknown"
      });
    }

    // We're making an assumption here: there is no error when callObject is
    // first assigned.

    callObject.on("error", handleErrorEvent);

    return function cleanup() {
      callObject.off("error", handleErrorEvent);
    };
  }, [callObject]);

  /**
   * Start a timer to show the "click allow" message, when the component mounts.
   */
  useEffect(() => {
    const t = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: CLICK_ALLOW_TIMEOUT });
    }, 2500);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearTimeout(t);
    };
  }, []);

  function getTiles() {
    let largeTiles = [];
    let smallTiles = [];
    Object.entries(callState.callItems).forEach(([id, callItem]) => {
      const isLarge =
        isScreenShare(id) ||
        (!isLocal(id) && !containsScreenShare(callState.callItems));
      const tile = (
        <Tile
          key={id}
          videoTrack={callItem.videoTrack}
          audioTrack={callItem.audioTrack}
          isLocalPerson={isLocal(id)}
          isLarge={isLarge}
          isLoading={callItem.isLoading}
          Name={callItem.Name}
        />

      );
      console.log(callItem.Name);
      if (isLarge) {
        largeTiles.push(tile);
      } else {
        smallTiles.push(tile);
      }
    });

    return [largeTiles, smallTiles];
  }

  const [largeTiles, smallTiles] = getTiles();
  const message = getMessage(callState);
  return (
    <div className="call">
      <div className="large-tiles">
        {!message
          ? largeTiles
          : null /* Avoid showing large tiles to make room for the message */}
      </div>
      <div className="small-tiles">{smallTiles}</div>
      {message && (
        <CallMessage
          header={message.header}
          detail={message.detail}
          isError={message.isError}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example on codesandbox? At first sight, it seems that the `.forEach` content is never used. How do you build `largeTiles`, `smallTiles` and how are these two scripts related ? Currently, it look like a complete non sens.

Comment: I would suggest explaining what you want to do first, `useRef` doesn't seem like it's appropriate here.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I tried to trimmed the code

Comment: Thanks, I agre with @EvanTrimboli, please explain what you want to do, and why, and what do you do to solve it, what do you expect and what do you have. A runnable example would help. You have many undefined values in your code. I already named a few.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Actually I want this string  `"Mohd Jamshaid"` should assign in `callItem.Name`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa EvanTrimboli I updated full code.

Comment: The `forEach` loop is useless, perhaps you want to build an array with `.map` ? It also seems that you could simplify this code a lot by removing all the unecessary ref. Using `useState` when you need to have a state value that change (if any). Please simplify the code, remove all functions to the minimum. How is `getTiles` called ? I believe you should not use getter and directly use components. Show the full JSX that you are trying to render.

Comment: I want Name value in `Tile` Component. which is giving me undefined.  Rest props like videoTrack, audioTrack etc are working fine if I log it.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa Updated Entire Code.

Comment: Try to use name?? instead of Name

Comment: I am trying to assign Name to each participants. I am building a Video Conference app.

Comment: where should I use name?

Comment: The `useEffect` for name doesn't make sense. Why are you putting a ref on the `p` tag at all? You're already putting `props.Name` in there.

Comment: then where do i assign value for `props.Name`?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Can you please tell me?